# Mysql saving user's and server's current time difference

Tags: mysql, datetime, utc

I have a web server which will be serving people from around the world.

The time is a really important matter in my application, since a lot of queries are taking the time in consideration.

I need a way to store user's and server's time differences.

**For example:**

1. User login to server and send its current time.
2. Server's save the current time difference in mySql server
3. Every every time the server needs to use user's time in a query he knows how to calculate it since
   it knows the difference..

What i really need is the server's ability to calculate user's time according to server's own time.

I've read about using UTC time but i didn't really understand how to implement it...

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are in the US and i am in the UK. If we both check the UTC time at the same time (with whatever code/method) we should see the same result. Check out the different ways of getting [UTC timestamps in milliseconds](http://currentmillis.com/). Then, in theory, if you sync everything by UTC time (including the server) you don't really need to be aware of timezone offsets because these offsets are only relevant if you consider the server time is based on its local timezone.

In MySQL you can get a unix timestamp with UNIX_TIMESTAMP(). As far as i know it has granularity to the second, not millisecond (so you will get the number of seconds since 1970). You can also check out [UTC_TIME()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-utc_time-function.php) and [UTC_TIMESTAMP()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-utc_timestamp-function.php).

Comment: you are right but doesnt uk will utc+somthing and us as utc-something?

Comment: yes there is a difference in the time the clock shows: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zones_by_UTC_offset But the number of milliseconds passed since 1970.01.01 UTC is the same everywhere :)